# How do I use Ajax to verify query results?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have an HTML form and a JavaScript file that processes the form data (The event onsubmit=validate()). I am trying to use Ajax to send an ID to a PHP script. The PHP script should send back an array (JSON?). Each element in that array will be a column from a query, based on the ID that was sent. Then I want to compare the results found in the database with the one the user entered in the HTML form. My question are: Is this good practice? How can I implement this idea if it is, if not, what is the better approach?

I am putting what I have so far and will add to the morning. I have not been able to find what I am looking for on my own. Here is my code so far:

```
   function validate() {
    var first=document.getElementById("b1j").value;
    var last=document.getElementById("b2j").value;
    var password=document.getElementById("b3j").value;
    var ID=document.getElementById("b4j").value;
    var number=document.getElementById("b5j").value;
    var email=document.getElementById("b6j").value;
    var cbox=document.getElementById("check");
    if(first.search(/^[aA-zZ]+[aA-zZ]$/) < 0) {
        alert("Invalid first name.");
        return;
    }
    if(last.search(/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]$/) < 0) {
        alert("Invalid last name.");
        return;
    }
    if(password.search(/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_\-=+<>]).{3,10}/) < 0) {
        alert("Invalid password.");
        return;
    }
    if(ID.search(/[0-9]{4}/) < 0) {
        alert("Invalid ID");
        return;
    }
    if(number.search(/^(\d{3}[\s\-]){2}[0-9]{4}/) < 0) {
        alert("Invalid phone number.");
        return;
    }
    if(email.search(/^\w*@\w{2,5}\.com$/) < 0 && cbox.checked) {
        alert("Invalid email."); 
        return;
    }
    verify(ID);
   }
   
   function verify(id) {
     //communicate with the php script
     //if not verfied, stay on same page and give an alert saying why the credentials are wrong.
     //verfied? Go to the page that is being requested in the options (implement in the php script along with session info)
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     
     xhr.onload = function () {
     
       //Completely lost beyond here.
       const result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       if (result.found !== 0) {
         
       }
       else {
       
       }
     };
     alert("sending");
     xhr.open("GET", "../php/vmc4a4.php?id="+ID, false);
     xhr.send();
     alert(errorMsg);
   }
```

```
    <?php

    //Server info hidden
    $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      
      $query = "SELECT * FROM Stylists WHERE Stylists.id = '$id';";
      $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is a dreadful idea. If your server is going to return data based only on the ID then there's nothing stopping an attacker firing a string of requests with different IDs and reading your entire database. Send all the data in the form to the server and do the verification there. Then return some sort of Yes/No response.

Comment: Very unsafe approach, do verification at server side then return some response.